# How to save SQL query results to tab delimited text file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, export

I'm using the following SQL script to generate 4 output queries.  I would like to know if there is a way to save the results directly to a tab text delimited file.

For example: `SELECT * FROM <table> Export TO "C:\TEMP\Output.txt"`

Thanks

```
DECLARE @DLNK_POS As TABLE
(
    TERMINAL int,
    OPERATOR int,
    TRANSNUM int,
    SEQNUM int,
    STORE_NO int,
    DL_NO int,
    DL_SDATE date,
    DL_EDATE date,
    POS_DATE date,
    PALLET varchar(1),
    ODS varchar(1),
    UPC bigint,
    PACK int,
    SIZE varchar(10),
    ITEM_DESC varchar(40),
    P_BB_AMT decimal(10,2),
    S_BB_AMT decimal(10,2),
    SOLD_QTY int,
    PRICE money,
);


WITH [CTE] As
(
    SELECT
        F1.TERMINAL,
        F1.OPERATOR,
        F1.TRANS_NO,
        F1.SEQ_NO,
        F1.STORE_NO,
        FDL.DL_NO,
        FDL.DL_SDATE1,
        FDL.DL_EDATE1,
        F1.POS_DATE,
        FDL.PALLET,
        FDL.ODS,
        F1.UPC,
        FDL.DL_PACK,
        FDl.DL_SIZE,
        FDL.DL_ITEM_DESC,
        FDL.P_BB_AMT,
        FDL.S_BB_AMT,
        F1.QTY,
        F1.PRICE,
    FROM [MSTR_DB].[dbo].[POS] As F1
    INNER JOIN [MSTR_DB].[dbo].[DEAL] As FDL
    ON (F1.UPC = FDL.DL_UPC)  And (F1.POS_DATE BETWEEN FDL.DL_SDATE1 And FDL.DL_EDATE1) And FDL.S_BB_AMT != 0
)

INSERT  INTO @DLNK_POS SELECT * FROM [CTE];
```

> /*** OUTPUT 1 ***/ SELECT * FROM @DLNK_POS;
>
> /*** OUTPUT 2 ***/ SELECT DL_NO, DL_SDATE, DL_EDATE, PALLET, ODS,
>   STORE_NO, PACK, SIZE, UPC, ITEM_DESC, P_BB_AMT, S_BB_AMT,
>   SUM(SOLD_QTY) As SOLD_QTY FROM @DLNK_POS GROUP BY DL_NO, DL_SDATE,
>   DL_EDATE, PALLET, ODS, STORE_NO, PACK, SIZE, UPC, ITEM_DESC, P_BB_AMT,
>   S_BB_AMT ORDER BY DL_NO, STORE_NO, UPC;
>
> /*** OUTPUT 3 ***/ SELECT DL_NO, DL_SDATE, DL_EDATE, STORE_NO,
>   SUM(SOLD_QTY) As SQL_QTY FROM @DLNK_POS GROUP BY DL_NO, DL_SDATE,
>   DL_EDATE, STORE_NO ORDER BY DL_NO, STORE_NO
>
> /*** OUTPUT 4 ***/ SELECT DL_NO, DL_SDATE, DL_EDATE, PALLET, ODS,
>   PACK, SIZE, UPC, ITEM_DESC, P_BB_AMT, S_BB_AMT, SUM(SOL_QTY) As
>   SOLD_QTY FROM @DLNK_POS GROUP BY DL_NO, DL_SDATE, DL_EDATE, PALLET,
>   ODS, PACK, SIZE, UPC, ITEM_DESC, P_BB_AMT, S_BB_AMT;

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: I'm currently using MS SQL 2012

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help you in **your code**. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read through the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask a question that is acceptable in the forum.

Comment: Have you tried `xp_cmdshell` with `bcp`?

Comment: No, I have not.  I've use bcp in the pass but on simple queries.  I'm not sure how to setup the entire script into a variable to use in bcp.  I'm wondering if it would be easier to accomplish this in C#.

Comment: See if this helps, it was my answer for another csv question, ignore the email part https://stackoverflow.com/a/43991158/3309109

Comment: Use BCP. You can store your query in script file and call it from bcp.

Comment: Okay, I will try using BCP - thanks